# Pull all pull reviews in github api

Tags: postman, github-api

I want to be able to pull all github pull reviews via the api. At the moment you can only GET a review via a specific number as per the below

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:pull_number/reviews
```

Is there a way that instead of just 1 pull_number i can pull through all pull reviews?

Im using Postman for the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) iterating over the pull requests and getting reviews list for each one. But it would give you a bunch of issues that have no reviews, so you would need to use the Github Search API to filter only issues of type PR that have been reviewed :

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:mui-org/material-ui%20type:pr%20-review:none

Using GraphQL v4 you can get the reviews easily :

```graphql
{
  search(type: ISSUE, query: "repo:mui-org/material-ui type:pr -review:none", first: 100) {
    issueCount
    nodes {
      ... on PullRequest {
        number
        reviews(first: 100) {
          nodes {
            author {
              login
            }
            bodyText
            state
            createdAt
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bertrand, thanks for the details above but how do i put it all together. If i use graphql what do i use as the endpoint for the GET?

Comment: Ignore me ive worked it out and the above worked perfectly. Thanks